# My.Settings don't show in PropertyGrid

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to use a propertygrid in a certain project to display `My.Settings`. But whenever I start the project the property grid stays blank.

The sub where the propertygrid is used:

```
Private Sub frmMain_Load()
    lblNothingFound.Visible = False

    '// Set listview column sizes
    Filename.Width = 135
    AssyNo.Width = 112
    BomRevision.Width = 44
    OrderQty.Width = 67

    '// Show settings in PropertyGrid
    PropertyGrid1.SelectedObject = My.Settings

End Sub
```

Settings:

```
 <userSettings>
      <Converter_Import.My.MySettings>
        <setting name="BJISource" serializeAs="String">
            <value>"Path1"</value>
        </setting>
        <setting name="BJITarget" serializeAs="String">
            <value>"Path2"</value>
        </setting>
        <setting name="BCISource" serializeAs="String">
            <value>"Path3"</value>
        </setting>
        <setting name="BCITarget" serializeAs="String">
            <value>"Path4"</value>
        </setting>
    </Converter_Import.My.MySettings>
</userSettings>`
```

I really don't know if the above would be enough
Any advice would be much appreciated!

Boris

Comment: My PropertyGrid isn't blank.  Don't know what you are doing.

Comment: It may be a problem in the code we cant see.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: Your load method isn't handling the load event.  Just override it: `Protected Overrides Sub OnLoad(e As EventArgs)`  Or just put that code in the form's constructor.

Comment: @LarsTech, Thank you very much!

Comment: Never type in your own event handlers - thats what the drop downs are for at the top of the code editor